# Compiler fails to identify overloaded delete operator causing LNK2019

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, visual-studio-2017

I used [Pavel Yosifovich's article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2016/11/30/using-modern-c-in-driver-development/) to develop a windows kernel driver using c++ (not for a special reason, just to study it).

In his article, Pavel shows how to overload new and delete operators and how to implement vector.

when I tried to compile the driver with the overloaded delete operator it failed due to linker error (LNK2019) which caused because the compiler didn't compile the right delete operator.

my code:

```
Vector<ULONG> *vector = nullptr;

void* __cdecl operator new(size_t size, POOL_TYPE pool, ULONG tag = 0) {
    return ExAllocatePoolWithTag(pool, size, tag);
}
void __cdecl operator delete(void* p) {
    ExFreePool(p);
}

NTSTATUS Init()
{
    vector = (Vector<ULONG>*)new(NonPagedPool, 'DaOr') Vector<ULONG>();

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS Fin()
{
    // case 1:
    delete vector;
    // case 2:
    // delete (void*)vector;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are two cases that resulted in different linker error messages:

Error in case 1: (in this case, hovering over the delete operator in Fin() showed me that it is NOT my overloaded delete operator **"void operator delete(void*, unsigned int)"** (VS2017)).

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator
>   delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z) referenced in function
>   "public: void * __thiscall Vector::`scalar deleting
>   destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_G?$Vector@K@@QAEPAXI@Z)

Error in case 2: (in this case, hovering over the delete operator in Fin() showed me that it is my overloaded delete operator **"void operator delete(void* p)"** (VS2017)).

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator
>   delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z) referenced in function
>   "long __stdcall Fin(void)" (?Fin@@YGJXZ)

In both cases, it seems that the linker looks for the same delete operator only the delete operator is referenced from different places.

**The problem was solved** by changing my delete operator's signature:

from

```
void __cdecl operator delete(void*)
```

to

```
void __cdecl operator delete(void*, unsigned int)
```

the compiler identifies my delete operator.

**My questions:**

1. why does in case 1 the linker searched the delete operator in the Vector? I can sort of understand the confusion of the compiler that it tried to call the Vector destructor - but I would like an explanation.
2. why does in case 2 when I hover over the delete operator in Fin() it shows "operator delete(void*)" but the error shows "operator delete(void*, unsigned int)"? (I know it could be VS2017 error, but can it be something else?)
3. why in both cases, I pass only one parameter to delete, and yet it identifies the "operator delete(void*, unsigned int)" as if I send it two parameters, and not "operator delete(void*)" like it should?

Comment: See (5) (or possibly 3) in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete